# A function on ordinals.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Denote by $L$ the set of all non-zero countable limit ordinals. Is there an injection $f\colon \omega_1\times L\to L$ such that $f(\alpha,\beta)>\beta$ for all $(\alpha,\beta)$ in the domain of $f$?

Comment: What you ask is obviously impossible. This is because if $f(\alpha,\beta)=\omega$, then $\beta<\omega$, a contradiction. If you require that the strict inequality holds for all elements of $L$ except for $\omega$, then maybe it's possible.

Comment: you're right. I modified my question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partition $L$ as $\{L_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$, where $|L_\xi|=\omega_1$ for each $\xi<\omega_1$. For $\xi<\omega_1$ let $\eta_\xi=\min L_\xi$; we may assume that $\langle\eta_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\rangle$ is strictly increasing. If $\{\alpha_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ is a strictly increasing enumeration of $L$, then $\alpha_\xi\le\eta_\xi$ for each $\xi<\omega_1$. Necessarily $\eta_0=\alpha_0=\omega$.

Let $X=\{\xi<\omega_1:\eta_\xi=\alpha_\xi\}$, let $L_0'=L_0\cup X$, and for $\xi<\omega_1$ let

$$L_\xi'=\begin{cases}
L_\xi\setminus\{\eta_\xi\},&\text{if }\xi\in X\\
L_\xi,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and $\eta_\xi'=\min L_\xi'$; clearly $\eta_\xi'>\alpha_\xi$ for $\xi>0$. For each $\xi<\omega_1$ enumerate $L_\xi'=\{\beta_\gamma^\xi:\gamma<\omega_1\}$, and define

$$f:\omega_1\times L\to L:\langle\gamma,\alpha_\xi\rangle\mapsto\beta_\gamma^\xi\;;$$

then $f$ is a bijection, and $f(\gamma,\alpha_\xi)>\alpha_\xi$ unless $\gamma=\xi=0$, in which case $$f(0,\alpha_0)=f(0,\omega)=\omega=\alpha_0\;;$$ a single exception at $\omega$ is unavoidable if $f$ is to be a bijection.

Comment: Very nice! I too thought it screamed Fodor in the beginning and then I realized the inequality was the wrong way.  I really like this solution, I was hoping to get something with Cantor normal form, but I'm not so sure that route will work anymore.